# LSTM with attention. TypeError: 'module' object is not callable. What's wrong with my implementation?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm, attention-model

1270 timesteps, each timestep with length 36; 10 classes

```
max_length = 1270
step_dim = 36
_input = Input(shape=[max_length, step_dim])

activations = LSTM(128, return_sequences=True)(_input)

# compute importance for each step
attention = Dense(1, activation='tanh')(activations)
attention = Flatten()(attention)
attention = Activation('softmax')(attention)
attention = RepeatVector(1270)(attention)
attention = Permute([2, 1])(attention)


sent_representation = merge([activations, attention], mode='mul')
sent_representation = Lambda(lambda xin: K.sum(xin, axis=-2), output_shape=(64,))(sent_representation)

probabilities = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(sent_representation)
```

gives:

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

What does it mean and how do I resolve it?

Comment: what is this merge(). from where you imported it. please provide complete script and in which line you are getting the error

Comment: @devSpartan merger() is a standard Keras layer. The error is referring to the merge() line.

Comment: Sorry dude, I found no keras layer named merge. There are other merging layers e.g, add, concatenate, dot, minimum, etc

Comment: @devSpartan yeah, using Multiply layer now. And changed input to RepeatVector() to 128. Now, it works.

Answer (score 0):

There is no more 'merge' layer, as you can see [here](https://keras.io/api/layers/merging_layers/#concatenate). You should use `Concatenate` instead.

Here is a useful [guide](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3921#issuecomment-335457553) on how to convert old `merge` code into functioning Keras code.